# Is it possible to have two DateCompontents for one Local Notification?

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to set two different times for Local Notifications - the default one being 10 am every day (if the user does not touch the date picker to pick their own notification time AKA it is nil), and one based on the user's input. The user input one does work and sends notifications every day, but if no time is chosen the default time does not work.

This is my code, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I basically want to check that if the user input is NIL it should revert to the default time set.

In settings:

```
IBOutlet var userDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

IBAction func pickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var selectedTime = Date()
    selectedTime = sender.date

    // convert to data type DateComponents
    let convertedSelectedTime = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: selectedTime)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    delegate?.sendNotification(with: convertedSelectedTime)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedTime, forKey: "SavedTime")
}
```

In AppDelegate:

```
func sendNotification(with userSelectedTime: DateComponents?) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Testing"
    content.body = "testing"
    var defaultTime = DateComponents()
    defaultTime.hour = 10
    defaultTime.minute = 00`// trying to set default time to 10 am if user never picks a time`
    let components = userSelectedTime ?? defaultTime//option between the two
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. All of its fields are optional. So you can use those you need.

```
DateComponents(calendar:timeZone:era:year:month:day:hour:minute:second:nanosecond:weekday:weekdayOrdinal:quarter:weekOfMonth:weekOfYear:yearForWeekOfYear:)
```

---

```
let triggerDaily = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,
  timeZone: Calendar.current.timeZone,
  hour: 10, // Use 22 if PM 
  minute: 00,
  second: 00,
  nanosecond: 00)

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: false)
```

---

#### More info

[DateComponents - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents/1948879-init)

---

#### Update

In `pickerValueChanged`, you are schedulling notification every time `DatePicker` value is changed. That is bad. There you should only store date.

```
func pickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.date, forKey: "SavedTime")
}
```

`sendNotification` should only send notification.

```
func sendNotification(with dateComponents: DateComponents) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Testing"
    content.body = "testing"
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}
```

---

`UIApplication` has alife method that is called when an App goes to background. You can schedule notifications there.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let date = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "SavedTime") as? Date
    if let date = date {
        let convertedSelectedTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,], from: date)
        sendNotification(with: convertedSelectedTime)
    } else {
        let dateComponent = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,
          timeZone: Calendar.current.timeZone,
          hour: 10, // Use 22 if PM
          minute: 00,
          second: 00,
          nanosecond: 00)
       sendNotification(with: dateComponent)
    }
}
```

Use `SavedTime` if it exists in `UserDefaaults`. Else use `10:00`.

---

If you use SceneDelegate, use `sceneDidEnterBackground` instead of `applicationDidEnterBackground`

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {

}
```

---

They both are life-cycle methods.

#### More info.

[Managing Your App's Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle)

[UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication)

Comment: Thanks for your email! However, where can I present the option to also take in the userSelectedTime? The default time (10am) is supposed to be a fall back option if the user doesn't pick anything

Comment: @Tine Where have you used userDatePicker? Don't you have a Save button?

Comment: It is in the settings viewcontroller (mentioned above). That then gets passed on as a parameter to the sendNotification function in AppDelegate. 

I think use the using the nil coalescing optional in:

let components = userSelectedTime ?? defaultTime

hoping that if userSelectedTime doesn't exist yet it will pick defaultTime instead. This is obviously flawed but I am not sure how to go about it

Comment: Wow thank you! For some reason it would not work with AppDelegate, but it did with SceneDelegate. Thank you very much